# Lucene: assigning custom ids?

Tags: java, lucene

Can I assign my custom ids to Lucene indexed documents instead of automatically generate new ids ?

I'm asking this because I already have ids in my collection. A specific field is used for that.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - in fact this is the only way to do it. (Lucene can't generate IDs for you. The thing that it calls "doc IDs" are internal only and are subject to change at Lucene's whim.)

You would just have a field called "myID" or whatever, and mark it as stored.

Comment: So, I've added the myID field but how can I replace these ids "doc" I see in the results: [doc=0 score=10.122469, doc=1 score=3.5992513, doc=11 score=0.78047055] ?

Comment: @Patrick: Those are internal Lucene IDs and you should ignore them. To get your field's value just use `doc.GetField("myID")`

Comment: These results are the output of topDocs = searcher.search(booleanQuery, 220000); topDocs.scoreDocs; How can I get the array of scoreDocs with my custom ids instead of the inner ones ?

Comment: @Patrick: See any Lucene tutorial. For example step #4 in [Lucene in 5 minutes](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-in-5-minutes.html) will tell you this.

Comment: ok, I see. So I use the internal "doc" id to get the document and print a specific field (in my case "myId")